# Problems when clicking on image in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an image gallery using javascript and when I click on an image to enlarge it, instead of enlarging to the center of the page it enlarges completely off the page. How do I get the images to move to the center while they are enlarging? My gallery is due at midnight and I just can't seem to get it to work! My prof hinted that I need to make the images move up and to the left while they are enlarging. I would really appreciate it if someone could help!

Comment: How can we help you without seeing any code?

Comment: Add some code or else we cannot help

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code I can only explain the concepts. You have to use both JS and CSS. Here is an example:

This the JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            if($(".myImage img").width() > $(".myImage").width()) {
                var url = $(".myImage img").prop("src");
                $(".myImage").css("background","url("+url+") no-repeat center center").empty();                
            }else{
                $(".myImage img").width($(".myImage").width()).height($(".myImage").height());
            }
        });
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="myImage">
        <img src="http://cdn.walyou.com/wp-content/uploads//2010/12/facebook-profile-picture-no-pic-avatar.jpg" width="350"/>
    </div>
```

and finally the code in the CSS:

```
.myImage { border:1px solid #000; width:300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden; }
```